# remove trailing number from url via .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I added this rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-[0-9]+/$ /$1/ [L,QSA]
```

to remove a trailing number preceded by a hyphen from an url on a WordPress site

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-[0-9]+/$ /$1/ [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

But it doesn't seem to do the trick, to me the regex seems ok but I presume it conflicts with the other rules

Comment: I'd suggest putting that rule ahead of the rule just prior to it

Comment: Is there a trailing slash on the URL like your rule specifies?

Comment: yes there is a slash at the end however there is not always a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Additional 2 lines to remove the trailing -Number from the URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/(.*)-(?:[0-9]*)?/?$    [NC]
RewriteRule .*   %1        [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php   [L]
</IfModule>
```

The additional 2 lines redirect permanently

`http://example.com/any/number/of/folders/anything-NUMBER`

To:

`http://example.com/any/number/of/folders/anything`

The `-NUMBER` combination must be the trailing string in the URL, with or without trailing slash.

The hyphen `-` is removed always, even when there is no number. If you want to keep it, replace

`RewriteRule .*   %1        [R=301,L]`  with

`RewriteRule .*   %1-       [R=301,L]`

Permanent redirection is used to show the substitution URL in the browser's address bar. For silent mapping, remove `R=301` from [R=301,L].

Comment: Hi, Can you tell how I can remove the exact same things but only if there is more than 6 trailing numbers ?

Answer (score 0):

RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)-[0-9]+/?$ $1/