# Remove trailing number in Wordpress via .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, trailing

I have tried this: [remove trailing number from url via .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635438/remove-trailing-number-from-url-via-htaccess)

But when I reload my page, it produces an error on reload. Are their any other ways on doing it? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Post your .htaccess code and give an example of the request with the numbers

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER: I read that the hyphen-number makes the page unique. Since we have created the same name of the page but actually deleted it, Wordpress gave it a unique name by adding -number. I read you have to permanently delete the pages you made with the same name in the Trash folder then change the permalink. That's all :)